# How to define derivative in Minkowski space

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

My understanding of derivative is like this: it is the unique linear mapping that sends the difference in $x$ to the difference in $f(x)$ when the difference in $x$ is small. To put it more rigorously, $g$ is the derivative of $f$ if and only if for every positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that
$$\lVert f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)-g(x)(\Delta x)\rVert \le \epsilon \lVert\Delta x\rVert$$
for every $\lVert\Delta x\rVert < \delta$. Is it the same in Minkowski space where $\lVert \Delta x \rVert$ may be equal to $0$?

Comment: Short answer: yes, using the Euclidean norm on $\mathbf{R}^4$.

Answer (score 2):

I've only seen this definition of derivative (The [Fréchet Derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)) used for normed spaces - in the case of a semi-norm such as your example, things get <s>very nasty. For example in order for $f$ to be differentiable by this definition we must have $f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + g(x) \Delta x$ whenever $\Vert \Delta x \Vert \le 0$, i.e. $f$ must be affine outside the light-cone of any particular point. I'm pretty sure that by pasting together this fact at multiple base points you can conclude that $f$ must be affine.</s>

The better abstract definition of derivative to use in this setting is the [Gâteaux derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative), which is defined independent of the norm. It thus treats Minkowski space identically to Euclidean space, producing the familiar differential/gradient whenever it exists. If you require the Gâteaux derivative to be linear to call the function differentiable then you recover exactly the classically differentiable functions.

Comment: In my question, $\lVert v \rVert = \sqrt{|\eta(v,v)|}$ which is always a non-negative real number. And $\lVert f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)-g(x)(\Delta x)\rVert = 0$ does not neccessarily mean that $f(x+\Delta x) = f(x)+g(x)(\Delta x)$.

Comment: @siyu: that second point is very true, I guess things are not as bad as I thought. Regardless I doubt the Fréchet derivative is a useful concept here.

Answer (score 1):

Minkowski space is $\mathbf{R}^4$, considered with the Lorentz form $g : \mathbf{R}^4 \times \mathbf{R}^4 \to \mathbf{R}$ defined by 
$$g(X,Y) = x^0y^0 - \mathbf{x}.\mathbf{y},$$
where we use the notation $X = (x^0, \mathbf{x}) \in \mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R}^3$.

In physics, differential calculus is done on Minkowski space using the standard Euclidean structure for $\mathbf{R}^4$. However, physicists use operators like the four-gradient rather than the Fréchet derivative.

The four-gradient is defined for a function $f : \mathbf{R}^4 \to \mathbf{R}$ by 
$$\text{Grad } f = \bigg(\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}, -\nabla f\bigg)$$
where $\nabla$ is the gradient on $\mathbf{R}^3$ and the partial derivatives are calculated using the usual definitions for $\mathbf{R}^4$.

Similarly, the Fréchet derivative of a function on Minkowski space could be considered using the Euclidean structure for $\mathbf{R}^4$: for example, to show that [the transformation law for the Christoffel symbols implies that Poincaré transformations are affine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12664/proving-that-interval-preserving-transformations-are-linear).

Comment: One potential issue with this approach is that the topology induced by the Minkowski pseudonorm is not the same as the topology on $\mathbb{R}^4$, so it is not clear that everything carries over. e.g. is it *a priori* obvious that the Euclidean derivative is the "best linear approximation" in the sense of the Minkowski pseudonorm?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  ... if you have any insight into how to make it mathematically rigorous, I would be interested to hear it.

Answer (score -1):

In a Minkowski space such a derivative does not exists in general. To see this focus on direction of $\Delta x$ ,if its direction changes we have a different value for $g$ so we can not define $g$ as function of $x$.

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear. $g(x)$ is not a number but a linear function which takes $\Delta x$ as its argument.

Comment: Ok. I'm aware of that. As I know in general case (Minkowski norm does not obtain from an inner product) such a derivative does not exists. If you have an example please let me know and correct myself.

Comment: If $f(x)=x$ then such derivative trivially exists.

Comment: It seems that you want to define an operator which its domain includes a very special functions and name it an derivative. Lots of (really lot of!) smooth function does not have derivative in this way. Any way,thank for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

Restating with bold vectors for clarity:

> $\nabla {f}({\bf x})$ is the gradient of $f$ at point $\bf x$, iff for
>   all $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that if $|{\bf \Delta x}|<\delta$: $$\left| f({\bf x}+ {\bf \Delta x})- f({\bf x})-\nabla{f}({\bf x})\cdot({\bf \Delta x}) \right| < \epsilon |{\bf \Delta x}|$$

In theory, when $|{\bf \Delta x}|=0$, the gradient vector thus defined can take on any value. In practice however, if $|{\bf \Delta x}|=0$, this means we are taking the derivative along the edge of the light cone. Since all physical phenomena occur only in the interior of the light cone, this isn't really a problem.

Comment: Can you give an example where $\nabla f$ is well-defined using this definition?